# write a loop that will print out (on a new line) all names that begin with L or l (both uppercase and lowercase) that are longer than 5 characters

Tags: php, arrays, loops, printing, echo

I have the following array

$person_array = array('Leanna', 'derek', 'Lisa', 'John', 'lancelot', 'Michael', 'norman', 'Lawrence of Arabia');

I need to write a loop that will print out (on a new line) all names that
  begin with L or l (both uppercase and lowercase) that are longer than 5 characters

could you please help me

Comment: Can you show your effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by following code :

```
    <?php
    $person_array = array('Leanna', 'derek', 'Lisa', 'John', 'lancelot', 'Michael', 'norman', 'Lawrence of Arabia');
    foreach($person_array as $sarray){ 

        if(substr($sarray,0,1) == 'L' || substr($sarray,0,1) == 'l') 
        {
        if(strlen($sarray)>=5){
        echo $sarray.'<br>';

        }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Cool, Thanks. Could you help me with the following aswell:Create an output array that contains all distinct characters (Uppercase and Lowercase)
from the strings contained within the array above. Use only the str_split function 
 and any of the Array functions to do so.

Comment: So basically you want that names in array ?
And you can not ask two question like this :) I 'll help you for sure but post new question everytime(stack overflow has no limit for question) so that if any other user come across in such problem then they can find solution easily.